# How to implement `__setitem__` for `pathlib.Path`

Tags: python

As above. I made this attempt below but it throws an error:
I don't know how to mutate `self` to get what I want.

```
from pathlib import Path

class P(type(Path()), Path):

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        fullparts = list(self.parts)
        fullparts[key] = value
        return P(*fullparts)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return P(self.parts[key])

p = P("folder/subfolder/file.txt")
p[1] = "haha"  #
```

Desired outcome `folder/haha/file.txt`.

Actual outcome: object not changed!

Comment: Yes. I'd like that instead of returning something.

Comment: This didn't work? `self.parts = fullparts`

Comment: `AttributeError: can't set attribute`

Comment: Seems like you might have to define your own parts attribute along with a getter/setter