# Why doesn't pathlib.Path implement __add__?

Tags: python-3.x, pathlib

### Premise

A convenient but fragile path might be written in Python as a string

```
fdir = r'mydir/'
fname = r'myfile'
fpath = fdir + fname
```

This is a terrible practice (`np.inf` demerits), but the syntax is concise and readable (`+1` merits).

### Question

Should `pathlib.Path` have implemented an `__add__` method, which would amount to a little syntactic sugar.

`pathlib.Path` stores path elements internally as a tuple and constructs representations on demand, right? In theory, this shouldn't break anything within the class-- the `__add__` method would simply internally `self.joinpath(other)`.

Why wasn't this done, and what about this is unpythonic?

### Example

```
BASE = pathlib.Path('').resolve()  # some working directory
...
for fstring, stuff in zip(flist, queue):  # some stuff to output to file
   with open(BASE + fstring, 'w+') as f:  # <--- this is compact and readable
      f.write(stuff)
```

Here, the common task of appending to a path is represented as `BASE + string`, which is just prettier than `BASE.joinpath(string)`

An uglier example (I don't know why you would do this, but bear with me):

```
s1 = 'components'
s2 = 'arms'
s3 = 'bones'
s4 = 'humerus'

fpath = Path(s1).joinpath(s2).joinpath(s3).joinpath(s4)
```

Contrast with:

```
...
fpath = s1 + s2 + s3 + s4
```

### Related

- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0428/
- [How to implement `__setitem__` for `pathlib.Path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65607798/how-to-implement-setitem-for-pathlib-path)

### Note

Per iBug's response, this behavior does show up in the docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use) though I missed it in my searches.

Comment: Using `+` for that would have been way too confusing - does `Path('a') + 'b'` give `Path('ab')` or `Path('a/b')`?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely to your surprise, `pathlib.Path` *does* implement a `__truediv__` method, which correspond to the `/` operator, and works exactly like what you'd expect from an `__add__` method.

This sentence gives you an instant for your astonishment. You can now move on to the code:

```py
s1 = 'components'
s2 = 'arms'
s3 = 'bones'
s4 = 'humerus'

fpath = Path(s1) / s2 / s3 / s4
# PosixPath('components/arms/bones/humerus')
```

It's actually [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use).

Comment: Thanks-- that is in fact the behavior I alluded to.

The PEP has this to say about the div operator:

"The division operator came out first in a poll [10] about the path joining operator. Initial versions of pathlib [1] used square brackets (i.e. __getitem__) instead."

I guess it's easy to see how I overlooked it.